# ERROR: Could not build wheels for spacy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

[image]

Hi Guys, I am trying to install spacy model == 2.3.5 but I am getting this error, please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the similar error while executing `pip install -r requirements.txt` but for `aiohttp` module:

```
socket.c -o build/temp.linux-armv8l-cpython-311/aiohttp/_websocket.o
aiohttp/_websocket.c:198:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
#include "longintrepr.h"                                   
          ^~~~~~~                        1 error generated.
error: command '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang' 
failed with exit code 1
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install
pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Just in case I will leave here solution to my error. This error is specific to Python `3.11` version. On Python with `3.10.6` version installation went fine.

To solve it I needed to update `requirements.txt`.

Not working versions of modules with Python `3.11`:

```
aiohttp==3.8.1
yarl==1.4.2
frozenlist==1.3.0
```

Working versions:

```
aiohttp==3.8.2
yarl==1.8.1
frozenlist==1.3.1
```

Links to the corresponding issues with fixes:

- https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/6600
- https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/issues/706
- https://github.com/aio-libs/frozenlist/issues/305

Answer (score 4):

Try using python 3.6-3.9 instead, where there are binary wheels for `pip install` to use instead of having to compile from source.

(This is a conflict with python 3.10 and some generated `.cpp` files in the source package. Python 3.10 wasn't released yet when this version was published.)

Comment: It's not working dude

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

`!pip install spacy==2.3.5`

**Do not give space between** `==` and `2.3.5`

If you give any space between equal sign and version, it may give error.

Comment: HI sorry, I don't gave any spaces inbetween, here typo - sorry

Comment: Ran the above command with macbook air Intel OS 10.13.1 High Sierra (I have reasons to stay with) python 3.6.4 it hicupped installing 2.3.5 using above command, a bunch of red compile messages but then said:     Downloading thinc-7.4.5-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (987 kB) And now import spacy works. To clarify, pip install spacy without version would not complete. Latest spacy 3.7 dropped support for python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with this. In my case it was "nmslib". Along the way I also ran into CUDA problems, similar to [this](https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts/issues/648). Deleting my scispacy conda environment over and over again, I finally achieved a clean and fast install with this order:

```
# create new conda environment with Python 3.9 (to build wheels)
conda create -n scispacy python=3.9

# activate new environment
conda activate scispacy

# install other important packages (don't forget pytorch here! It is especially important as "pip install scispacy" would install it too, but then you would run into CUDA trouble)
conda install spyder numpy scipy pandas matplotlib sympy cython pytorch 

# install scispacy
pip install scispacy

# .. and its models (the ones you want, obviously)`enter code here`
pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.5.3/en_core_sci_lg-0.5.3.tar.gz
pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.5.3/en_core_sci_scibert-0.5.3.tar.gz
```